# How to deny a poweroff without killing a running script that will execute it?

Tags: linux, backup, shutdown, power-off

I have a backup script that executes the poweroff command to shutdown my machine once all backups are finished. However it happens that I want to deny the poweroff, but without killing the script process, as it would corrupt my backup and leave a bad mess.

How can I make the poweroff not execute without pausing or killing the script?

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/unfa/Scripts/Daily\ backup/backup.sh > ~/backup-unfa.log; echo "data thread finished" &
/mnt/system-backup/system-backup.sh > ~/backup-system.log; echo "system thread finished" &

sleep 1m
while [[ -n $(pgrep rdiff-backup) ]]
do echo "Backing up yo data, dude..."; sleep 3s
done
echo "POWER OFF"
poweroff
```

Answer (score 1):

The script will execute the poweroff command.
If you want that to fail, you can temporarily change the /sbin/poweroff file permissions so it is not executable.

First, become root to gain full access to protected system files:

```
sudo su
```

Now remove the "is executable" permission from the poweroff binary:

```
chmod -x /sbin/poweroff
```

After the script is finished remember to revert this change, as otherwise you'll be left with a non-working poweroff command:

```
chmod +x /sbin/poweroff
```

Tested, works well.